# How to tell Guest OS to treat USB port as network card?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, home-networking, gateway

**Computer 1**

- Motherboard 845GBV
- Host OS     Windows XP
- Guest OS    Linux slackware (via Virtual Box)
- Network     via USB modem
- USB port    3/6

**Computer 2**

- Motherboard Asus P7P55D-E Pro
- OS     Windows 7 x64
- Network     via USB modem, or 
          on-board network chip
- USB port    Plenty!!

1) Motherboard on computer 1 is possessed of 6 USB ports

2) USB modem (connecting to the internet) is plugged into one of the USB ports

3) Guest OS uses NAT to access the USB modem

4) I wish to start setting up a network where the Slackware guest OS on computer 1 is the gateway/firewall for computer 2

How should the Guest OS be told to use one of the USB ports (I only use 3 of them at present) as a Network Card?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the functionality of a USB port by "telling" it something.
You will need to install a **USB Ethernet adapter** in order to use one of the spare USB ports as a "Network Card".  If the USB (cable or xDSL) modem is *eth0*, then the new USB Ethernet adapter will show up as *eth1*.

Avoid the really cheap no-name adapters on *bay.  Choose a brand that has a full range of networking products and is more likely to have Linux support.

Answer (score 0):

If you have USB network adaptor, passing it through *should* work. I found that having driver support on the guest (naturally essential) and and host works with wireless USB network dongles, but i've not tried it with usb ethernet dongles.